# Date format conversion 'Wed Oct 20 16:42:04 +0000 2021' on Python

Tags: python, datetime

I wrote a script for receiving data from Twitter, now I'm doing column splitting, I want the date and time to be in separate columns.

I get a date like: Wed Oct 20 16:42:04 +0000 2021

I do it with the following code:

```
filtered_data['date'] = tweet['created_at']
```

Next, I want to convert this date at the time of receipt into two fields using datetime

```
date_formats = '%d-%m-%Y'
time_formats = '%H:%M:%S'
```

At the time of application:

```
filtered_data['date'] = datetime.strptime(tweet['created_at'], date_formats)
```

I get the following error:

```
time data 'Wed Oct 20 16:42:04 +0000 2021' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'
```

Tell me how I can do this transformation and is it possible to do it at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you want a datetime object:

given

```py
tweet['created_at'] = 'Wed Oct 20 16:42:04 +0000 2021'
```

use

```py
input_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y'

filtered_data['date'] = datetime.strptime( \
    tweet['created_at'], \
    input_format)
```

results in

```py
>>> filtered_data['date']
datetime(2021, 10, 20, 16, 42, 4, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

### If you want a formatted string as `'%d-%m-%Y'`:

given

```py
tweet['created_at'] = 'Wed Oct 20 16:42:04 +0000 2021'
```

use

```py
input_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y'
output_format = '%d-%m-%Y'

filtered_data['date'] = datetime.strptime( \
    tweet['created_at'], \
    input_format).strftime(output_format)
```

results in

```py
>>> filtered_data['date']
'20-10-2021'
```

### Reference

See [python `datetime.strptime` and `datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the current format first. See an example:

```
from datetime import datetime

my_date = 'Wed Oct 20 16:42:04 +0000 2021'
initial_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y'
final_format = '%d-%m-%Y'

new_date = datetime.strptime(my_date, initial_format).strftime(final_format)
print(new_date)
```

Output:

```
20-10-2021
```

So in your case, try:

```
filtered_data['date'] = datetime.strptime(tweet['created_at'], '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y').strftime(date_formats)
```

Comment: thanks) Everything works